# Have we achieved Elite Status on Philosophy.SE today?

Tags: discussion

Have we acheived 'leet status here on Philosophy.SE?

I have as evidence:

[image: Screen shot of active Questions and infobox]

Comment: Nice! Good job grabbing a screen shot :)

Comment: It's still the case, as of *this* comment (self-reference violations be damned) if anyone wants another shot in more stunning resolution.

Comment: It's definitely an interesting sign of the times :)

Comment: "3177" answers, anagram...

Comment: @stoicfury well, almost... :P

Comment: @commando yeah :P